# Como fazer um editor de texto simples com jQuery, PHP e BBCode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bbcode

Como posso formatar textos em um *textarea* com BBCode?
Tipo, criar um mini editor de texto com atalhos para parágrafo, negrito, centralizar, essas opções básicas, nada muito personalizado.

Comment: Essa pergunta na forma como está é muito ampla, e provavelmente será fechada como tal. Tente ser mais específico: seu problema é a edição no lado cliente, ou a integração com o servidor? com que tipos de texto você está lidando, texto comum com formatação, código, outra coisa? já tentou usar alguma ferramenta, mas não conseguiu e/ou não achou satisfatória (pelas razões X e Y)? Quanto mais contexto puder fornecer, melhor.

Comment: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1080/javascript-construindo-um-editor-de-texto.aspx tem bastante informaçoes no site do link acima.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sugiro procurar por um editor já pronto, por se tratar de uma funcionalidade comum é mais fácil que reinventar a roda. Uma busca rápida me levou ao [SCEditor](http://www.sceditor.com/), que parece ter tudo o que você precisa. Abra o site e, no demo, clique no último botão ("View source"): isso vai alternar entre o modo [WYSIWYG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) e o modo BB code.

Esse editor é software livre (licença MIT), de modo que você pode integrá-lo ao seu sistema sem empecilhos. Para utilizá-lo, basta incluir os scripts e folhas de estilo necessárias (escolha a modalidade com suporte a BB code):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="minified/themes/default.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="minified/jquery.sceditor.bbcode.min.js"></script>
<script src="languages/pt-BR.js"></script>
```

E chamar o plugin no seu elemento (`textarea`), passando as [opções](http://www.sceditor.com/documentation/options/) desejadas:

```
$("#meu_textarea").sceditor({
    plugins: "bbcode",
    style: "minified/jquery.sceditor.default.min.css",
    locale: "pt-BR"
});
```

Aqui está a [API](http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/). Para obter-se o valor que o usuário digitou, pode-se usar simplesmente [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) no `textarea` ou um método específico que pode [transformar o BB code em HTML](http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/getsourceeditorvalue/) para você ou [vice-versa](http://www.sceditor.com/api/sceditor/getwysiwygeditorvalue/) (cuidado: pode ou não ter implicações na segurança).

Comment: Obrigado, mas eu pensei que poderia aprender a criar um bem básico por mim mesmo, de modo a não ter que depender de programas de terceiros :s. Obg na mesma.